# Storing images for gallery to array

Tags: android, android-intent, android-imageview, android-arrayadapter, android-imagebutton

So I tried choosing Images **in gallery** using an `Intent`

I tried

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
```

How can I save the image chosen to an array, and every time I choose an Image it saves in the `array`.

Comment: Try to post your whole code.

Comment: use to store the exact image file path in arraylist.

Comment: post the class including the function onActivityResult()

Answer (score 0):

You can use following method to get all files list in an ArrayList.

```
private ArrayList<Uri> getFileList()
{
    ArrayList<Uri> fileList = new ArrayList<Uri>();
    try
    {
        String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Media._ID };
        Cursor actualimagecursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, proj,
                null, null, MediaStore.Images.Media.DEFAULT_SORT_ORDER);

        int actual_image_column_index = actualimagecursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < actualimagecursor.getCount() ; i++ )
        {
            actualimagecursor.moveToPosition(i);
            String fileName = actualimagecursor.getString(actual_image_column_index);
            fileList.add(( Uri.withAppendedPath( MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, fileName )));

        }
        return fileList;
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```